# Select Text in WebView when loading facebook

Tags: java, android

I am loading facebook in my webview in android studio,but I cant select the text of posts or comments,while if I load another website I can do that .Anyone knows how to enable that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting Text on mobile version of Facebook doesn't work in Chrome too. Try to disable Javascript in your webview.

Comment: This worked in some places but not where I need it,any way thanks